# Select a range of files using range in python

Tags: python, iteration, range

I want to know is there a way to select a range of files using python range command, actually I'm running modeler 9.11 for protein homology modeling?

This is the python script:

```
from modeller import *
from modeller.scripts import complete_pdb

log.verbose()    # request verbose output
env = environ()
env.io.atom_files_directory = './Build_models'
env.libs.topology.read(file='$(LIB)/top_heav.lib') # read topology
env.libs.parameters.read(file='$(LIB)/par.lib') # read parameters

for i in range(1, 5):
    # read model file
    code = "Brn3a.B99990000%00d1.pdb" % i
    mdl = complete_pdb(env, code)
    s = selection(mdl)
    s.assess_dope(output='ENERGY_PROFILE NO_REPORT', file='Brn3aloop.profile',
                  normalize_profile=True, smoothing_window=15)
```

I want to read a set of protein structures named like this saved on Build_models directory:

- Brn3a.B99990001
- Brn3a.B99990002
- Brn3a.B99990003
- Brn3a.B99990004
- Brn3a.B99990005

The output from the executable look like this

```
pdbnam_____E> Filename for PDB code not found: Brn3a.B9999000011.pdb
              Directories: ./Build_models
```

So how i set the range to select the list mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there; your format should be:

```
code = "Brn3a.B9999000%d.pdb" % i
```

You had a few too many zeros and a redundant `1`.

You also need to remember that the stop value in a range is *not* included, so to get the numbers 1 - 5 you need to add 1 to the stop parameter:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
```